# Почему индекс в массиве является строкой?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Почему в первом варианте тип переменной `i` строка, это же вроде индекс итеррации?

Нужен индекс в виде числа чтобы его умножать, но хотелось бы без лишних преобразовываний типов, так как массивы огромные.

Какой вариант лучше использовать, первый или второй, в чем преимущество обеих?

```js
let obj = {
  1234: {},
  2489: {},
}

let nums = Object.keys(obj).map(key => parseInt(key));

console.log(nums);

for (let i in nums) {
  console.log(typeof i, typeof nums[i]);
}

for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  console.log(typeof i, typeof nums[i]);
}
```

Comment: У объектов все ключи - строка.

Comment: @ksa то есть в js [ ] и { } это одно и тоже по типу?

Comment: Я тебе больше скажу - в JS все объект. Но у каждого типа добавлена своя "специфика"... :)

Comment: Вообще-то `obj` это не массив. Какой из двух вариантов лучше наверное зависит от того что вы собираетесь делать. Хотя перебирать массив (настоящий) через `for ... in` это плохая идея практически всегда.

Comment: P.S. возможно вам нужен [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 1):

В первом варианте тип переменной строка, потому-что for...in используется для перебора свойств объектов. Когда вы перебираете массив этим циклом, то перебираются ключи массива как объект.

Ключи у объектов строковые, отсюда и строковый тип у переменной i.

Массив в JavaScript это тоже объект, у которого есть свои методы и свой конструктор.

Во втором вашем варианте используется цикл, где вы сами инициируете переменную числом 0 и при каждой итерации увеличиваете его на 1 (инкриминируете). Поэтому там по логике не может быть строки, ведь вы увеличиваете не строку, а число.

Попробуйте вариант перебора

```js
for (const num of nums) {
  console.log(num);
}
```